how to print event information using etw in c++
Error: Unable to Start ETW Trace Session in C++ (Error Code 87)
I'm developing a C++ application to consume and print real-time events using Event Tracing for Windows (ETW). However, I'm encountering issues when trying to start the trace and register the provider. The errors are as follows:
unable to start trace 87
unable to register provider 87
These errors indicate ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER, but I can't identify which parameters are incorrect. Below is my code snippet:
#pragma once
#include <windows.h>
#include <evntrace.h>
#include <evntcons.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>



class EventProvider
{
private:
    TRACEHANDLE sessionhandle;
    TRACEHANDLE consumertrace;
    GUID eventprovider;
    LPCWSTR sessionname;
    PEVENT_TRACE_PROPERTIES properties;
    bool running;
public:
    EventProvider(LPCWSTR, GUID);
    void initProperty();
    void startTrace();
    void consumer();
    static void run(PTRACEHANDLE);
    static VOID WINAPI eventcallback(PEVENT_RECORD);
    ~EventProvider();
};

EventProvider::EventProvider(LPCWSTR sessionname, GUID provider)
    : sessionhandle(0), consumertrace(0), eventprovider(provider), sessionname(sessionname), properties(nullptr), running(false)
{
    this->initProperty();
    this->startTrace();
    this->consumer();
}

void EventProvider::initProperty() {
    ULONG buffsize = sizeof(EVENT_TRACE_PROPERTIES) + 2 * sizeof(WCHAR) * 1024;
    this->properties = (EVENT_TRACE_PROPERTIES*)malloc(buffsize);
    if (this->properties == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Unable to allocate bytes for properties" << std::endl;
    }
    ZeroMemory(this->properties, buffsize);
    this->properties->Wnode.BufferSize = buffsize;
    this->properties->Wnode.Guid = this->eventprovider;
    this->properties->Wnode.Flags = WNODE_FLAG_TRACED_GUID;
    this->properties->LogFileMode = EVENT_TRACE_REAL_TIME_MODE;
    this->properties->Wnode.ClientContext = 1;
    this->properties->LogFileNameOffset = 0;
    this->properties->EnableFlags = EVENT_TRACE_FLAG_PROCESS;
    this->properties->BufferSize = 64;        // Size of each tracing buffer in KB
    this->properties->MinimumBuffers = 1;
    this->properties->MaximumBuffers = 5;
    this->properties->MaximumFileSize = 0;

}
VOID WINAPI EventProvider::eventcallback(PEVENT_RECORD pevent) {
    std::cout << "i have bbencalled" << std::endl;
}
void EventProvider::startTrace() {
    DWORD status = StartTraceW((PTRACEHANDLE)sessionhandle, sessionname, properties);
    if (status != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        std::cout << "unable to start trace " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }

    DWORD status2 = EnableTraceEx2(this->sessionhandle, &this->eventprovider, EVENT_CONTROL_CODE_ENABLE_PROVIDER, TRACE_LEVEL_INFORMATION, 0, 0, 0, NULL);
    if (status != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        std::cout << "unable to register provider " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }
}
void EventProvider::run(PTRACEHANDLE handel) {
    if (ProcessTrace(handel, 1, 0, 0) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        exit(0);
    }
}
void EventProvider::consumer() {
    EVENT_TRACE_LOGFILEW trace;
    TRACE_LOGFILE_HEADER* pheader = &trace.LogfileHeader;
    ZeroMemory(&trace, sizeof(EVENT_TRACE_LOGFILEW));
    trace.ProcessTraceMode = PROCESS_TRACE_MODE_REAL_TIME | PROCESS_TRACE_MODE_EVENT_RECORD;
    trace.EventRecordCallback = (PEVENT_RECORD_CALLBACK)(EventProvider::eventcallback);
    trace.LoggerName = (LPWSTR)R"(ANTI TRACER)";
    TRACEHANDLE handle = OpenTraceW((PEVENT_TRACE_LOGFILEW)&trace);
    if (handle == INVALID_PROCESSTRACE_HANDLE) {
        std::cout << "Unable start trace session : " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }
    consumertrace = (TRACEHANDLE)handle;
    std::thread thread(run, (PTRACEHANDLE)consumertrace);

}


I need help identifying and fixing the issue. My goal is to consume events in real-time and print each event's output to the terminal. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I think FlushTimer  should be set to 1 or a higher value, also  you could need  EVENT_TRACE_INDEPENDENT_SESSION_MODE. See https://github.com/microsoft/perfview/blob/51ec1dffe9055ab58ba1b13d1b716b36760ed895/src/TraceEvent/TraceEventSession.cs#L2364 for a working example although it is in C#.

I think before you start your trace, make sure if previous traces are running you need to stop them. So just call ControlTrace(0, SessionName, sessionProperties, EVENT_TRACE_CONTROL_STOP);
I hope this should clear your errors. Also in this->properties->Wnode.Guid = this->eventprovider; I think this is not event provider, this is the GUID for session.
